# UWP - Prevent NavigationViewItemHeader from being clipped

Tags: c#, uwp, clip

I am writing a UWP app that has a `NavigationView` containing `NavigationViewItemHeader`s:
[image]

```
   <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem Content="Home" Tag="home">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE80F;"/>
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>

        <NavigationViewItemSeparator/>
        <NavigationViewItemHeader x:Name="ThemesHeading" Content="Themes"/>

        <NavigationViewItem Content="Themes" Tag="themes">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE771;"/>
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
```

*(and so on)*

However when I collapse the view, the headers get clipped:

[image]

What should I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Increase the left margin of item headers:

```
<NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Themes" Margin="33,0,0,0"/>
...
<NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Builds" Margin="33,0,0,0"/>
```

[image]

**Solution 2**

Disable compact and expanded display mode of the `NavigationView` by setting the `CompactModeThresholdWidth` and `ExpandedModeThresholdWidth` to some big number:

```
<NavigationView CompactModeThresholdWidth="100000" ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="100000">
```

[image]

**Solution 3**

Bind the `Visibility` property of item headers to the `IsPaneOpen` property of the `NavigationView` as André B suggested, only use `x:Bind` instead of `Binding` since it doesn't need a converter:

```
<NavigationView Name="MyNavigationView">
    ...
            <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Themes" Visibility="{x:Bind MyNavigationView.IsPaneOpen, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    ...
            <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Builds" Visibility="{x:Bind MyNavigationView.IsPaneOpen, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    ...
</NavigationView>
```

[image]

Comment: Also prevents false header showing when window width at minimum.
CompactModeThresholdWidth="1"                        AlwaysShowHeader="False"

Answer (score 0):

Define the name attribute, `x:Name`, of your NavigationView object, so you can access to its `IsPaneOpen` property. Use the Binding property `ElementName`, to get the element you want to use as your binding Source, with the uniquely identifier that you defined with the attribute.

The `IsPaneOpen` property as the name suggests identifies whether the Pane is opened to it's full width, which can be used to toggle the Visibility of your `NavigationViewItemHeader.Visibility` property!

```
<NavigationView x:Name="NavView" ... >

    <NavigationViewItemHeader x:Name="ThemesHeading" Content="Themes" 
            Visibility="{Binding IsPaneOpen, 
                        ElementName=NavView, 
                        Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>

</NavigationView>
```

Since the `IsPaneOpen` property returns a `Boolean` value, while `Visibility` is  of type `Enum`, you need to create a **Converter**, so your Boolean state can be assigned to a value which makes sense to the Visibility Property. 
For our situation, we want :

`NavigationView.IsPaneOpen = True` -> `NavigationViewItemHeader.Visibility = Visibility.Visible`;

`NavigationView.IsPaneOpen = False` -> `NavigationViewItemHeader.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`;

By default Binding's Mode is set to `OneWay`, which is exactly what you want, since your NavigationView is the one who is going to dictate the visual state of the NavigationViewItemHeader, and you don't need the other way around.

Create a class, which is going to be your Converter! Your class has to inherit from `IValueConverter` interface. In my case, I created a folder called "Converter" and defined the BooleanToVisibilityConverter there.

```
namespace MyUWPApplication.Converter
{
    class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public BooleanToVisibilityConverter()
        {
        }

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value is bool && (bool)value)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

In your XAML's page include the `Namespace` above (*yours is going to be different*), like this:

```
xmlns:common="using:MyUWPApplication.Converter"
```

Bellow, define your Converter's resource and give it a key, so you can reference it in the `Binding` definition.

```
            <Page.Resources>
                <common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
            </Page.Resources>
```

The converter resource `BoolToVis`, is being referenced in the Binding definition, and whenever there's a change to the `IsPaneOpen` property, the Convert function is going to be called to convert our Boolean value to Visibility.

**Result:**

[image]