# Hiding the NavigationViewItemHeader based on NavigationView Mode in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I'm using [NavigationView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) component for UWP which introduced with Windows 10 Fall Creators Update Version 1709 (OS build 16299).You can add some headers to nav area written as in the document:

> **The NavigationView pane can contain:**
>
> - Headers, in the form of NavigationViewItemHeader, for labeling groups    of items

I added two header like this:

[image]

However, I cannot hide the headers if app view state is changed and NavigationView display mode settled as "Compact". Also, NavigationView **have not** events like paneClosed or PaneOpened which are included in the SplitPane component.

[image]

I tried this code block, however it is not the complete solution:

```
private void Navigator_DisplayModeChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewDisplayModeChangedEventArgs args)
    {

        if (args.DisplayMode == NavigationViewDisplayMode.Compact && Navigator.IsPaneOpen)
        {
            Other.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            Main_Operations.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        else
        {
            Other.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            Main_Operations.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

If you can suggest a solution in this matter, I am delighted. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about old good visibility binding? Something like that (given the fact Navigator is the name of NavigationView itself):

```
<NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Header here" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Navigator,Path=IsPaneOpen}"/>
```

Also, you may find this discussion useful: [UWP - Prevent NavigationViewItemHeader from being clipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955807/uwp-prevent-navigationviewitemheader-from-being-clipped)

Comment: Thanks @ Yury Schkatula :) Both your solution and this are running:
 <NavigationViewItemHeader Content="Themes" Visibility="{x:Bind Navigator.IsPaneOpen, Mode=OneWay}"/>